# PyCharm not generating docstrings and no settings under Python Integrated Tools

Tags: python, pycharm, documentation, docstring

I'm trying to generate the docstrings to document my python functions, but when I'm going to

`PyCharm` `>` `Settings` `>` `Tools` `>` `Python Integrated Tools`

I find an empty window with no options and in particular no `Docstrings` `>` `Docstring format` `>` `reStructuredText` which is what I need to configure the docs format as my colleagues.

[image]

In addition when I click on the lightbulb near the function name and click on "Insert a documentation string stub" nothing happens.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? I'm using `PyCharm 2021.1.1 (Professional Edition)` on macOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `Python Integrated Tools` the list in the left column that says "Nothing to show" is populated from the open Projects. In the screenshot your file/directory tree shows a `.vscode` folder that isn't necessary to PyCharm, this would indicate that the PyCharm project folder called `.idea` must also have been copied from your shared project.

The solution is to delete the `.idea` folder and reopen PyCharm so the IDE can recreate its project folder. The reason is that the `.idea` folder contains a number of absolute file paths that are different between the computers.